# How can I modify individual elements of a vector?

Tags: c#, arrays, vector, emgucv

I want to read from and write to individual elements of a [`VectorOfFloat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/1f5ec683-8143-18ed-815e-1f2812ff960a.htm). The problem is that there's no setter defined, which makes the brackets + index way of accessing the elements read only.

```
VectorOfFloat vector = new VectorOfFloat(5);
// vector[2] = 2.5F; // does not work
```

There's a workaround:

1. convert to array with `ToArray()`
2. modify array as desired
3. write array back with `Clear()` and `Push()`

```
float[] array = vector.ToArray();
array[2] = 2.5F;
vector.Clear();
vector.Push(array); // does work but is retarded

Console.WriteLine(vector[2]);
```

This seems to be very cumbersome just to write one element **Is there a more direct approach to this?**
Also, what is the missing setter worth if I can work around it?

Comment: I don't know if it's _safe_ (from OpenCV implementation point of view) but you may simply `float* ptr = (float*)vector.StartAddress.ToPointer();` inside an `unsafe` context where you can also directly write `ptr[2] = 2.5f;`.

Comment: THis seems like a really awkward data type. Why not just use std::vector<float> ?

Comment: `VectorOfFloat` provides an `IntPtr` property named `Ptr`. Use that to gain access to a `foat*` pointer reference in an unsafe code block.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct. The way to gain access to the unmanaged array is trough the `StartAddress` property returning an `IntPtr`.

```
lock(vector) 
{
    var ptr_array=(float*)vector.StartAddress.ToPointer();
    ptr_array[4]=1.0f;    
}
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: I cannot set an individual element, because it's unsafe, but I can nuke the entire data structure and replace it with something completely different and do so safely?

Comment: You are not replacing the data structure. `VectorOfFloats` is an unmanaged type (C array) and you are accessing the elements with low lever memory operations bypassing the higher level indexing which does not allow you to set values. Just be careful and don't go nuts with pointers and always keep them in local context (don't return them from methods).

Comment: I do, in the workaround that I posted in my question.